# Javascript local folder selector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

There is a JavaScript component or a AngularJs directive that allows me to select a local folder.
For example, as the component of IntelliJ Idea "open project".

The aim is to obtain folder's path, nothing else. I'm not interested in the content, so, components such as file uploader or similar are useless.

Comment: There isn't anything a web server can usefully do with information about the file system of the visitor's computer. The browser won't expose that information to websites.

Comment: Browsers don't allow for getting absolute path as that would be a security violation.